# SQL Query for correlated tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables named General , Apartment , RoomsAndAmenities and BasisInfo.
In General table columns are GeneralId , Name , ApartmentId
In Apartment table columns are ApartmentId
In RoomsAndAmenities table columns are RoomsAndAmenitiesId , ApartmentId
In BasicInfo table columns are BasicInfoId , bedrooms , RoomsAndAmenitiesId.

I wants to get the Name column from General where bedrooms=1

plz help out me.

Thank You

Comment: Post the query you have tried so far.

Comment: select distinct general.name from general
inner join rooms_and_amenities on rooms_and_amenities.apartmentID = general.apartmentID
inner join basic_information on basic_information.roomsAndAmenitiesID = basic_information.roomsAndAmenitiesID
where basic_information.bedrooms='1'

Answer (score 0):

Alter procedure FilterApartmentByBedroom
@bedroom varchar(255)= null
As
Begin
select distinct 
general.name 
from general
inner join rooms_and_amenities on rooms_and_amenities.apartmentID = general.apartmentID
inner join basic_information on basic_information.roomsAndAmenitiesID = rooms_and_amenities.roomsAndAmenitiesID
where bedrooms=@bedroom
End